# How to make GtkEntry to stop reversing x alignment in RTL layout?

Tags: right-to-left, gtkentry

GtkEntry get his alignment property from xalign parameter. but when you start typing
in some RTL language (ex. Arabic) it reverses the alignment ([this feature is also noted in GTK reference](https://developer.gnome.org/gtk2/stable/GtkEntry.html#gtk-entry-set-alignment)). how can I stop this feature and make the alignment permanent, independent of input language?